# I can't update SQL by Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to update a value in a MySQL database with this code.

```java
public static void editProduct(ProductDB x) {
    try
    {
      String query = "UPDATE products SET product_name = ? , price_per_unit = ? , product_description = ? , product_image  = ? WHERE product_id = ?";
      PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);        
      st.setString(1, x.product_name);
      st.setDouble(2, x.price_per_unit);
      st.setString(3, x.product_description);     
      if(x.product_image != null) {
          System.out.println("xx");
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ImageIO.write(x.product_image , "png" , baos);
          byte [] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
          st.setBytes(4, buffer);         
      }else {
          byte [] buffer = new  byte[0];
      st.setBytes(4, buffer);
      }
      st.setInt(5, x.product_id);         
      st.executeUpdate();
      st.close();
      System.out.println("xxx");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ProductDB x = new ProductDB(0, textField_ProductName.getText().trim(),
                Double.parseDouble(textField_productPrice.getText().trim()),
                textField_ProductDescription.getText().trim(), (BufferedImage) imagePanel.getImage());
        ProductManager.editProduct(x);
        load();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ProductFrmae.this , "Edited");
        
    }
});
```

Code printed "xx" and "xxx" and no exception caught.

And it already have "Edited" pop up.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I can't see you starting any database transaction here for the update statement

Comment: Have you checked the produced SQL and if it is correct/how you expect it? Maybe its just an obvious error like that the `WHERE product_id = ?` doesn't match any rows and therefor nothing is updated.

Comment: I just assume that the `0` parameter in the `ProductDB` constructor is the `product_id`? Do you have a product with `product_id`=`0` in the database? Otherwise the `WHERE` clause will cause that UPDATE statement to not affect any rows.

Comment: Most likely your DB is not in auto-commit mode, so you have to invoke `conn.commit()`. In general, your exception handling needs a lot of work and you aren't using try-with-resources, which doesn't help. Print the result of `executeUpdate()` - if it's a 0, that means no row fits your WHERE clause and thus the UPDATE statement did nothing.

Comment: The executeUpdate method returns the # of affected rows.  You ignore it.  Do you know that the method returns a 1?  I would check that.  Should be easy to figure out if you step through with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of i if you do this? It should give you the number of rows affected.
int i=st.executeUpdate();

Comment: it show valve of i equal 0 sir.

Comment: Then, please check your query. If you execute it directly using any SQL client, does it show any rows impacted? You can do a SELECT using the product_id to see if a record is retrieved for performing update operation.

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much. I can find the problem. thank you sir.